# Evaluating a limit with variable in the exponent

Tags: limits, logarithms

For
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1- \frac{2}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{x}{2}}$$ 
I have to use the L'Hospital"s rule, right? So I get:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{2} \log\left(1- \frac{2}{x}\right)$$
And what now? I need to take the derivative of the log, is it:
$\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{2}{x}}$  but since there is x, I need to use the chain rule  multiply by the derivative of $\dfrac{x}{2}$  ?

Answer (score 4):

Recall the limit:
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{a}y\right)^y = e^a$$
I trust you can finish it from here, by an appropriate choice of $a$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist in working with the l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x2\log\left(1-\frac2x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac2x\right)}{\frac2x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac2{x^2}\frac1{1-\frac2x}}{-\frac2{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{1-\frac2x}=-1$$

Thus, the limit is $\,e^{-1}\,$ ...

Comment: LOL , i got it now and in the denominator it"s $\frac{2}{x}$ because since you are moving the expression$\frac{x}{2}$ "down" to keep it"s value you "reverse" it , right?   If i am wrong , sadly i don"t get it , again :(

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

We know, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$$

Put $n=-\frac x2, \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac 2x\right)^{-\frac x2}\right)^{-1}=e^{-1}$

Comment: Not quite. There is a $-$ sign.

Comment: Some care with the minus sign is due here.

Comment: @user17762, can we leave something for the user?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, apparently we can't: you added the complete solution.

Comment: @DonAntonio  As did you...

Comment: Indeed so, Am...but I am not against that *in this case*, and in others as well.